# animate view transition when rotating Ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, rotation

Hi and thanks in advance for any responses.

I have an IPad app with two different views: one for portrait, one for landscape.
When I rotate the device, the transition between the views is not very smooth.I wanted to animate the transition between the two views so that it looks better.
This is what my code looks like for my rotation:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        self.view = corePlotContent.view; //make graph the landscape view 
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(-360)); 
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0);
    }else{
        self.view = portraitView;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1004.0);
    }
}
```

I think I need to override "willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" method and add some animation there but I'm not sure how to write the code. I haven't animated anything before so I'm not making any progress. Could someone please help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to fix the frame and coordinate system of your graph by hand since the UIViewController actually rotates its view accordingly.

Use something like this to have it automatically resized when the frame of the main view changes:

```
corePlotContent.view.autoresizeMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And use the `layoutSubviews` method in your graph view to do any local changes for the graph.

The lack of performance probably comes from extensive drawing during the rotation animation (the graph is redrawn for every frame during the rotation). I suggest you could use *willRotateToInterfaceOrientation* to disable redrawing of the graph for a moment and re-enable it in the call to *didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation*.

Also you can use Instruments with the CPU Profiler instrument to detect the bottleneck within your code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I was just wondering if I could make the transition smoother with just animation because I see some white space for just a sec when the landscape view pops in.

Answer (score 3):

The method: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is called just before the user interface begins rotating, it's used to prepare view for rotation - to setup state of view before the transition animation occurred.

Basically, you do not need to override this method, unless you want to disable view interactions, stop media playback, or temporarily turn off expensive drawing or live updates during the view transition animation. This method is **not called within the animation block**.

Instead, you should use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method. This method **is called from within the animation block** that is used to rotate the view - every visual property change made inside this call will be properly animated.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Great tip - thanks for this. Saved me a lot of needless work.